How to send an ECR message to a POS device?
I need to send some "amount of money" command to a POS device to initiate a credit card validation.
They say I need to send something like this, some kind of datagram protocol:
00 1A 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 1C 1C 1C 1C 1C 1C 1C 1C 1C 1C 1C

The first 2 characters is the header, size of message.
I tried something like this:
s :=     #$00#$1A#$30#$30#$30#$30#$30#$30#$30#$30#$30#$30#$30#$31#$30#$30#$30#$1C#$1C#$1C#$1C#$1C#$1C#$1C#$1C#$1C#$1C #$1C:
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_8Bit;
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 3000;
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(s);

But the POS device remains silent. I need to return some answer.
Example in their PDF:


Which Delphi version are you using? If it is 2009 and newer you may have to declare your s variable as AnsiString instead of regular string. This is due the fact that in newer Delphi version default string type is Wide String where each character is stored as two bytes. You should also show us official documentation for your specific POS terminal or at least provide a link to one. The documentation should provide needed information for data packet structure that needs to be sent to the POS.

You really should not be using a string for this kind of data (even with the 8bit encoding). This is simply not a textual protocol, so you should use a TIdBytes or TMemoryStream instead so that you can send binary data correctly.
